# i want to align this image to center but it's not working

Tags: html, css

In the above code I used `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` properties to align the image to center. I want to align this image to center but it's not working.

- What is wrong with this code?
- Are there any alternative methods?

```css
#boom{
  margin-top: 30%;
  height: 4%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="image1.jpg" id="boom">
```

Comment: add `display: block`, as By default the `img` is a `display: inline-block` *DOM* element and `auto` `margin` won't have any effect on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `text-align:center`

```html
<div id="boom">
 <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png" >
</div>
<style>
#boom{
 margin-top: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#boom img{ 
    width:50%;
}  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'd use flexbox.. It's becoming evermore popular.

Here's what I'd do:

```css
.imageContainer
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Gingerbread_House_Essex_CT.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Seriously? just to center align the image?

Comment: That's what he wants to do for now.. Flexbox is great for pretty much anything you do CSS wise. No time like the present to get used to using it..

Comment: Yep, `flex` is really an amazing property but when used *wisely*.

Comment: I totally agree, but it is good for even the simplest of tasks for basic practice and such. It has made CSS so much more enjoyable to do when using it.

Answer (score -1):

Add `display:table;` into your code

```
#boom{
        margin-top: 30%;
        height: 4%;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display:table;
    }
```

Comment: Why table specifically?

Comment: Better you have check this [link](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)

Comment: but in this case `display:block` and `display:table` achieve the same result, why use table? is more confused for beginners

Comment: The `block` value of the display property forces an element to behave like block-level element, like a <div> or <p> element...  `table` elements behave like  <table> HTML elements. It defines a block-level box.